# How can I get saved image location in React Native?

Tags: image, react-native, path, location

This is a code of taking screenshot and save it to storage. Now I need the location of saved image for email attachment. How can I get that location?

```js
captureScreen({
      format: "jpg",
      quality: 0.8,
    })
    .then(
      uri => {
        CameraRollExtended.saveToCameraRoll({
          uri: uri,
          album: albumName,
        }, 'photo')
      },
      error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
    );
```

Comment: `uri` should be the location, try `console.log` to see what's in it

Comment: uri is temporary location that not exist after save. I need the location that was created by saveToCamera().
I need to attach the captured screenshot to a mail. Are you know any way to do this?

Comment: You can still use the `uri` within the `then` callback. At the same time that you save to camera roll also use that `uri` to build the email.

Comment: I tried this but this method save image to a temporary file that will only exist for as long as the app is running. when Email app starts then it removed so I cant do that.

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation, `saveToCameraRoll` function returns a Promise which will resolve with the new URI. As such, following code should help you with the issue you are having.

```
CameraRollExtended.saveToCameraRoll({
  uri: uri,
  album: albumName,
}, 'photo').then((newUri) => {
  console.log('new location of image => ', newUri);
})
```

Comment: It returns a new uri but doesn't attach anything to the mail. New uri looks like "content://media/external/images/media/931". Is there need to add anything else?